# "Reversed" Caratheodory Condition?

Tags: measure-theory

My homework says to prove that if $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on a set $X$, and $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of of $\mu^*$-measurable subsets, then $(X\mathcal{M},\mu^*)$ is a complete measure space. The definition given for "$\mu^*$-measurable" is as follows:

A set $E\subset X$ is said to be $\mu^*$-measurable if for any set $A\subset X$, $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E\cap A) + \mu^*(E\cap A^c)$.

The definition I have seen before is:

A set $A\subset X$ is said to be $\mu^*$-measurable if for any set $E\subset X$, $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E\cap A) + \mu^*(E\cap A^c)$.

Are these equivalent conditions?

Comment: They are not equivalent.  The second definition is the correct one. One way to see this is to observe that using the second definition, if we choose $E=X$, the condition requires $\mu^*(X) = \mu^*(A) + \mu^*(A^c)$, which makes sense (we want to avoid sets $A$ which are so convoluted that the outer measure isn't additive over $A$ and $A^c$, because in that case the resulting "measure" would also not be additive), whereas using the first (incorrect) definition, if we choose $A = X$, the condition would require $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E)$, which is vacuously satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't be equivalent. The proof I know that the Caratheodory condition is equivalent to measurability also proves the same statement where Caratheodory condition holds only for all *measurable* $E$. So take a non-measurable set, $A$. Then the Caratheodory condition fails for $A$ with some measurable set $M$. But this is impossible if the "reverse Caratheodory" condition holds for $M$ with $A$.